# MySQL stored procedure only returns last row of data

Tags: c#, mysql

I am calling a MySQL stored procedure that should return about 6000 rows. But it is only returning the very last row. After looking at it, I am unable to see why it will only return the very last row of information.

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Net;
using FileHelpers;
using Stockton;
using System.IO;

namespace MassHistoricalDownload
{
    class Program
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        Reference r = new Reference();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.DownloadHistoricData();
        }

        public void DownloadHistoricData()
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = r.getMysqlConnection();
            string historicalDataPath = r.getHistFileLocation();
            string historicalDataExtension = ".csv";

            //Get the list of ticker symbols as well as the last date for which historical data was downloaded for that stock
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("call stockton.pullHistSymbolAndDate()", conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            //Download the files into the HistoricalData file
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string stockSymbol = rdr["symbol"].ToString();
                string stockLastDate = rdr["histDate"].ToString();

                //Check if the stockLastDate is empty and put int the oldest date if it is
                if (stockLastDate == null || stockLastDate == string.Empty)
                    stockLastDate = r.getOldestTradeDate().ToString();

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(historicalDataPath, stockSymbol + historicalDataExtension)))
                    {

                        sw.Write(client.DownloadString(string.Format(r.getYahooDownloadPart(), stockSymbol, stockLastDate)));
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    [IgnoreFirst(1)]
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class HistoricalStock
    {
        public string infoDate { get; set; }
        public double stockOpen { get; set; }
        public double stockHigh { get; set; }
        public double stockLow { get; set; }
        public double stockClose { get; set; }
        public int stockVolume { get; set; }
        public double adjClose { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MySQL Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`meggleston`@`%` PROCEDURE `pullHistSymbolAndDate`()
BEGIN
select
    c.symbol,
    hd.histDate
from
    company c
    left join historical_data hd on
        hd.symbol = c.symbol
        and 
        hd.histDate = (select max(histDate) from historical_data where symbol = c.symbol);
END
```

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` statement is probably the problem. Shouldn't the `hd.histDate` predicate be under its own `WHERE` clause instead of as a `JOIN` criteria?

Comment: What happens if you run the query directly (outside of the sproc), in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: It works just fine in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Please post the rest of your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the sql as:

```
select
    c.symbol,
    max(hd.histDate) as histDate
from
    company c
    left join historical_data hd on hd.symbol = c.symbol
    group by c.symbol
```

This would definitely return all symbols from the company table along with their last histDate.

EDIT

In your c# while loop you keep overwriting stockSymbol and stockLastUpdate variables. Their value will be the last record's value at the end of the loop. Perhaps you want to store the returned values in an array or a list.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement on the sql query.  But, the original problem exists where only the last row is returned.

Comment: They are stored in a list of sorts.  The reader should act like the list that I iterate through and store the data until I need it.  Correct me if I'm wrong there.

Comment: What happens if you execute directly the select query from the c# code rather than to call a stored procedure?

Comment: What if you change the commandtype to stored procedure **and** pass only the name of the stored procedure to the commandtext, so no call keword?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`