# mariadb always returning last row from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, phplist

I'm facing a problem very similar to this issue:

[MySQL stored procedure only returns last row of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701668/mysql-stored-procedure-only-returns-last-row-of-data)

Let me explain the scenario first.
I'm using phplist and I have created a custom attribute acting as "per user token"; it is used to create a custom unsubscribe links.
Sometimes I'm in the need to get such token manually knowing the user email address.

So, here is the two involved tables are (note: only relevand fields here):

- **phplist_user_user**: id,email
- **phplist_user_user_attribute**: attributeid,userid,value

With dbeaver ide, executing the following query I correctly get the user token:

```
SELECT value AS token FROM phplist_user_user_attribute WHERE attributeid=3 and userid=(SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM phplist_user_user WHERE `email`='useremail@domain.ext');
```

[image: Corect token]

If I put this query inside a stored procedure instead it always returns **the very last token** inserted to the table, regardless the correctness of email:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `phplist`.`GetTokenFromEmail`(IN `email` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    
    SELECT value AS token 
    FROM phplist_user_user_attribute 
    WHERE attributeid=3 
      and userid=(SELECT MAX(`id`)  
                  FROM phplist_user_user 
                  WHERE `email`=email);

END
```

[image: Wrong token returned]

[image: Wrong token whatever the input]

Checking at phplist_user_user_attribute table it equals to the very last row:

[image: last row of table]

This is a standard/default phplist installation, so I'm probably doing something wrong with the procedure I don't really understand what.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE `email`=email
```

Both columns are taken from `phplist_user_user` table - so the condition value is always TRUE until `phplist_user_user.email` is NULL.

Remember - if query's rowsource contains more than one table (including a case of copies of the same table) then specify table name/alias for EACH column name.

Comment: damn... I came from sql server world and I used to name parameters same as the fields without any issues... I didn't noticed it. I renamed the parameter and it is working, thank you!

Comment: @Squiffy Renamed parameter is a placebo. In compound statement always use a rule - column name always is accompanied with table alias, if no table alias then this is local variable.